# Elemento sai do lugar em "out-zoom"

Tags: css, posicionamento

[Neste site](http://www.emagrecerdireito.com/agency), o menu é uma `ul inline`, está dentro da `div` com largura indefinida de cor escura. Na `ul` coloquei `margin-left` para alinhar com os blocos de baixo...

Acontece que em outra resolução ou quando tiro o zoom ele sai do lugar, ao contrário dos outros elementos.

Estou com o mesmo problema no logotipo, por isso botei ela dentro de um parágrafo com `align-center`.

Como posso resolver isso?

```
.menu{ /* a div do menu logo acima dos blocos, resto do site*/
    padding:0.1px;
    background-color:#4e4c4f;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.menu ul{ /* o menu*/
    margin-left:420px;
}
```

Comment: O que é "out-zoom"? No conteúdo da pergunta não há nenhuma referencia a isso...

Comment: @brasofilo eu quis dizer mudança de resolução, em especial quando da zoom out no browser.

Comment: Ahhh, então é legal [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer isso, assim quem quiser responder tem todo o panorama na primeira leitura.

Comment: Acho que vou desistir dessa pergunta e aprender bootstrap para nao passar mais por isso. O que vc acha?

Comment: @ropbla9 cedo ou tarde você vai esbarrar em coisas que o bootstrap não tem nativamente e precisar de CSS puro, então no fim é bom dominar o CSS mesmo que vá usar um framework no futuro.

Comment: SOpt: sempre tem um craque no sábado à noite para tirar aquela pequena dúvida de CSS :))

Comment: @Bacco, até quanto à posicionamento? Todo meu "sufoco" é devido a posicionamento uaheu

Comment: @brasofilo Por que é sempre você o Bacco ou Sergio que me responde? huaheua

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que estás a manipular a posição do teu menu fazendo uso de uma margem esquerda, mas a mesma é sempre igual consoante o zoom dado à página.

## Solução menu ao centro

Se pretendes que esteja sempre centrado, basta retirar a margem esquerda do teu `.menu ul`, e na tag `nav` defines:

```css
nav{
  text-align:center;
}
```

O resultado visual é o mesmo e sempre que fazem ampliação ou redução da página, o menu está sempre alinhado ao centro.

[image: Simulação do resultado final]

---

## Solução menu alinhado pela esquerda dos blocos

Referiste nos comentários que a ideia é ter o menu alinhado à esquerda em relação aos blocos por baixo do mesmo.

Para que seja possível, a tua tag `<nav/>` deverá estar formatada da mesma maneira que a *wrapper* dos blocos de forma a ficarem na mesma posição em relação ao *viewport*.

```css
.menu nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

A tua `<ul/>` deverá então obter definições a a alinhem na zona pretendida:

```css
.menu ul {
    margin-left: 9%;
}
```

Desta forma, ficam ambos exatamente no mesmo lugar em relação à esquerda dos mesmos:

[image: Simulação do resultado final]

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta amigo. No entanto o que eu quero é deixar o meno alinhado à esquerda na medida da margem esquerda dos blocos abaixo. Entendeu?

Comment: Editei a resposta salientando como se pode obter esse resultado com base no teu código atual.

Comment: essa funcionou em partes, porque no Mozilla por exemplo definir o background do menu em px ele faz um espaçamento lateral na janela (quase imperceptivel). Mas eu posso criar outra div igual (100%) e colocar por baixo .